# Open policy agent policies administration

Tags: authorization, abac, open-policy-agent

I'm spiking OPA as a engine for ABAC authorisation infrastructure. With newer releases one can specify a service that is providing a bundle with data and rules for the policies. 
I was wandering if there is some opensource project that is addressing the policy management for OPA, like PAP-style from XACML standard? Some service framework that would at least manage lifecycle of a policies and would feed them to running OPA services?

Comment: Not that I know. You have to write your policies by hand. Try AuthZForce and ALFA instead

Comment: I was looking at AuthZForce, it did look good, but I had impression after reading some documentation on github  that it doesn’t provide much  PAP policy support, PAP and PDP were bundled together with some REST endpoints for policies CRUD, did I get it wrong?